# Laravel Storage::disk('public_path')->files() returning wrong path

Tags: php, laravel, file

In the following route, inspecting the image paths that this method returns, they all have "/categories/" at the start but this is not right, the actual path should be `/public/images/categories/gallery/1` not `/public/categories/images/categories/gallery/1`

```
Route::get('/categories/{group:id}', function (Group $group) {
    $images = Storage::disk('public_path')->files('images/categories/gallery/' . $group->id);
    return view('categories.index', ['group' => $group], compact('images'));
})->name('categories');
```

The following is an example of a route where it actually gets the correct paths

```
Route::get('/news', function () {
    $categories = Category::get();
    $images = Storage::disk('public_path')->files('images/news/gallery');
    return view('news', ['categories' => $categories], compact('images'));
})->name('news');
```

So my question is, why is it in the previous route, it returns the incorrect path with `/categories/` attached to the start but not in the one above, also how do I get the correct path in the first code example posted.

I tried changing the route to `Route::get('/{group:id}', function ... etc` and it works but I won't be able to use that because the url subdir will just be a number.

I also tried adding a forward slash to the path in the files() method so it was `->files('/images/categories/gallery/1');` but it still appends `/categories/` to the start.

This is the config for the method in filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'public_path' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(''),
        ],
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    ],

],
```

Comment: A temporary workaround I've gone with is using `'/category_group_{group:id}'` as the path but still wondering about this.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I tried to reproduce your error on my machine but couldn't. what's your laravel version?

Comment: `"laravel/framework": "^8.12"` When inspecting the element, it shows the correct path as well as in `print_r($images)` but hovering over the `src` attribute is when it appends `/categories/` in the tooltip, the images all have broken link icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in my php but in the vue component I was using which failed to place a forward slash at the start of the src path so I changed

```
<source media="(min-width: 768px)" :srcset="`${image}`">
```

to

```
<source media="(min-width: 768px)" :srcset="`/${image}`">
```

and it works.